# GPG - invalid marker packet

Tags: encryption, gnupg, decryption

can anyone help with the following gpg issue? Trying to decrypt an very old gpg-encrypted file (i assume it's a zip archive) fails with a simple "invalid marker packet". Trying --list-packets gives the following nice output:

```
gpg: invalid marker packet
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=1d)
gpg: [don't know]: partial length invalid for packet type 44
gpg: [don't know]: partial length invalid for packet type 25
gpg: vermutlich IDEA-verschlüsselte Daten
gpg: pinentry launched (70603 gnome3 1.1.0 /dev/pts/1 xterm-256color :0)
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=5b)
gpg: packet(14) with unknown version 68
gpg: vermutlich IDEA-verschlüsselte Daten
gpg: pinentry launched (70619 gnome3 1.1.0 /dev/pts/1 xterm-256color :0)
gpg: [don't know]: partial length invalid for packet type 4
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=68)
gpg: packet(2) with unknown version 228
gpg: Entschlüsselung fehlgeschlagen: Ungültiges Paket
gpg: WARNUNG: Botschaft wurde nicht integritätsgeschützt (integrity protected)
# off=0 ctb=ca tag=10 hlen=2 plen=94 new-ctb
:marker packet: [invalid]
# off=96 ctb=fe tag=62 hlen=2 plen=54 new-ctb
:unknown packet: type 62, length 54
dump: 4f 96 32 16 9c f3 b0 f6  c8 db fa 5f db ba 25 ad  9a 3a 8a 3a 53 82 20 86
  24: fe 0c 97 f9 ec 05 6c 3e  97 e5 7f 0e 7a 6d e3 32  f7 4d 24 55 c0 cd 69 6f
  48: f5 16 1a 94 70 a2
# off=155 ctb=fa tag=58 hlen=2 plen=166 new-ctb
:unknown packet: type 58, length 166
dump: 3b 43 46 66 5a 45 d4 54  36 cf 62 0d ac 41 a8 30  d6 a9 03 3a 93 9c 0d 88
  24: 57 31 f0 cb 20 8d ec 6d  f6 ab 25 05 7f 85 e3 7b  0c 3b 8c fb 10 3d 36 16
  48: 73 92 aa ac d7 85 4c 8f  06 fc f2 56 4a 31 a1 de  f9 59 c7 c0 7d 67 61 35
  72: a9 a5 48 c0 d9 0b c0 41  be 59 39 f9 af 56 9f d0  86 7c 44 99 53 2c 80 2c
  96: fe 9c eb e3 d0 d7 f4 11  89 81 90 d7 09 3d 29 ce  46 70 e9 b6 b0 e8 00 df
 120: ce 34 cc ee 90 30 3b 50  ea 77 30 48 86 9f f7 e6  b8 a2 06 a4 17 b6 68 d1
 144: b3 b3 64 36 97 4a 28 4e  02 74 6e 27 d8 67 e0 9f  0e c3 61 28 a7 ab
# off=325 ctb=a4 tag=9 hlen=2 plen=182
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 182
# off=509 ctb=f2 tag=50 hlen=2 plen=11 new-ctb
:unknown packet: type 50, length 11
dump: 31 f7 ad ce fb f8 55 a7  47 98 cc
# off=523 ctb=b9 tag=14 hlen=3 plen=30679
:key packet: [unknown version]
# off=31205 ctb=a6 tag=9 hlen=5 plen=2097775904
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 2097775904
# off=31224 ctb=e6 tag=38 hlen=2 plen=51 new-ctb
:unknown packet: type 38, length 51
dump: 6e c8 1f 4d 1d df 82 db  a9 66 0d 0d 68 06 8b 42  91 c3 0e 09 f3 a6 c3 f4
  24: ae 14 6e ee 59 fc 90 c8  d0 bb 7f 1c 89 80 27 28  d7 65 40 5e 7e 26 d4 e5
  48: 75 4f 5b
# off=31277 ctb=d0 tag=16 hlen=2 plen=72 new-ctb
:OpenPGP draft comment packet: "\xea`\x14m\xf8\xc1\xacM\x16\x98\xd8\xb6\x8c\xfb\x13+\xea\xf7\xcfR\xc2\xb9\xb4\xbbE]\xbf\xe8\x13l3fQt\xd2,G\x0e\x99M\x09fBa\xa5L\x09\x0fKJ\xafN`\x0d\xe70\x1c\x88\xc6i\xfd\x9b\xb4\x8b\xe7\x16\xa4\x96\xc6k\xd8\xe8"
# off=31351 ctb=dc tag=28 hlen=2 plen=123 new-ctb
:unknown packet: type 28, length 123
dump: e7 c2 43 4e b6 14 cc 3e  d2 33 a7 90 96 02 24 86  1b 0c a4 12 99 41 3a d3
  24: 38 da 38 59 d5 62 48 69  fe f8 ca a0 23 fe a0 85  d3 49 be 39 bb e2 0f 65
  48: a9 79 b5 8c 08 0e 6e e7  9e 05 f8 21 aa c5 3a 2c  de 57 14 6e d5 7d 57 88
  72: f2 23 94 8e 87 3e 94 fa  01 ba 7c 5c 0d 6d 34 cf  41 a0 4b 02 48 25 37 8e
  96: 29 89 a0 1b eb 59 46 c8  1c 41 70 b1 01 d9 f0 a4  a3 de 13 59 ad 68 12 84
 120: 1c 94 f5
# off=31476 ctb=8a tag=2 hlen=5 plen=2390932510
:signature packet: [unknown version]
```

Is there a way to overcome the "invalid marker packet" error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks more like your file is corrupted, and what GnuPG recognizes as packet types is in fact random data. Regular encrypted files don't have this many packets, and many of the values don't make any sense.

If it was a valid PGP encrypted file, GnuPG *would* have at least recognized everything in it.